# How to verify the field is text box or text area?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I am new to testing and selenium and got lots of doubts, one such is I can assert an element present but how to verify what it is actually, example if I have to check whether a particular field is text area or text box....

so is there any way to do it using selenium IDE?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use specific for every kind of elements assertions: for example
`assertEditable | locator` will fail if your field is label, `assertText | locator | pattern` will work for labels while for text box returned value will be '', `assertChecked | locator` will fail if your control isn't a toggle-button, `assertSelectedLabel | locator | pattern` will fail if your control isn't a drop-down and so on. 
Also you can just change your elements assertions with tags included into your locators: from `id=editField` to `css=input#editField` to be sure that this is an edit field or to `css=textarea#editField` to be sure that this is multilined textbox and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the point of your question is...

From the HTML point of view a textbox is   and a textarea is .  You can specify, and assert on locators that check specifically for these elements, e.g. using XPath locators:

- //input[@type='text]
- //textarea